# How to prevent pipe character from causing a Bad URI Error in Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

In implementing OAuth2 in my app, I need to handle URIs like:

http://localhost:3000/sessions/create/?code=lorem|ipsum

Not sure if it's a Rails 3 or Ruby 1.9.2 problem (maybe URI.parse), but in any event, WEBrick kicks `Error bad URI`.

Anyone know of a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to fix the typo in your title...

Comment: have you put `# coding: UTF-8` at the top of your files? 1.9+ is very sensitive about characters, sadly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into the same requirement (and problem) recently. On Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2.

It is not a problem for our staging/production environment (nginx), but I was interested to find out what the problem was with WEBrick. Turns out the issue is down in the URI::Parser.split method, specifically how it's pattern matching is seeded with the URI::REGEXP::PATTERN constants.

You can "fix" this by adding the following to a config/environments/development.rb (assuming you'd only be using WEBrick in dev .. or you could put it in a config/initializers file)..

```
# this allows WEBrick to handle pipe symbols in query parameters
URI::DEFAULT_PARSER = 
  URI::Parser.new(:UNRESERVED => URI::REGEXP::PATTERN::UNRESERVED + '|')
```

NB: that's setting :UNRESERVED => "-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d|"

Comment: `URI::Parser` ==> `NameError: uninitialized constant URI::Parser`. Any ideas? That's Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: yes, URI in 1.8 is very different, and much harder to patch without essentially re-writing big chunks of the URI module. IF you have this issue, best course is to upgrade to 1.9 or use something other than WEBrick

Comment: This is a really great solution.  One problem I was having was that even if you escape the URL, some sites (like yahoo) will forward you to a URL with unescaped characters (!) and OpenURI kept crashing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The initializer worked, but I ended up using URI.escape instead as it seemed cleaner and looks like it will handle more cases.

```
URI.join(origin_url, URI.escape(parsed_link)).to_s
```

Plus this code just didnt seem right

```
# I need this because URI.join in crawler.rb bombs with '|' symbols
old_verbose = $VERBOSE
$VERBOSE = nil
URI::DEFAULT_PARSER = URI::Parser.new(:UNRESERVED => URI::REGEXP::PATTERN::UNRESERVED + '|')
$VERBOSE = old_verbose
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just swapping in Thin for WEBrick and haven't had issues.