# Bad Request/Bad URI on production (Heroku) but not locally

Tags: ruby, http, heroku, sinatra, haml

Let me preface this by saying most of this application is a giant hack put together in a short window of time under pressure so I may have deeper issues.  This question will likely have some bad code in it.

I've built a Sinatra application to handle some tasks with purchase and sales orders in-house.  Part of that is to send a few parameters to one of the routes in the app which will then push those off to an API that does useful things with them.

Right now, I'm generating the links with paramaters from within a pretty ugly loop in HAML:

```
        %td
          - opts = JSON.generate({ "key" => d[d.keys.first]["key"], "sa_id" => d.keys.first, "site" => d[d.keys.first]["site"], "name" => d[d.keys.first]["name"], "recipient" => d[d.keys.first]["email"], "items" => d[d.keys.first]["descriptions"], "date" => d[d.keys.first]["ship_date"]})

          -if (d[d.keys.first]["email"]) && (d[d.keys.first]["site"] != "")
            %a{:href => "/notify?options=#{opts}", :title => "Deliver"} Deliver
          -else
            Deliver
          %a{:href => "/destroy?key=#{d.keys.first}", :title => "Destroy"} Destroy
```

When clicking hte "deliver" link (`%a{:href => "/notify?options=#{opts}", :title => "Deliver"} Deliver`) locally, everything behaves as expected.  My `/notify` route is called, it hands the parameters off to the desired API, and everything is rainbows and unicorns.  When I click that same link on Heroku, it throws a "Bad Request" stating "Bad URI".  The *only* difference between the two URLs generated is the hostname (localhost:3000 vs. myapp.herokuapp.com) and vimdiff confirms this.

Everything else being even, why would Heroku (using Webrick) kick back my URI when my local instance (Thin) doesn't seem to care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from Webrick to Thin on Heroku resolved this issue, though I'm not sure about the specifics as to *why*.

Comment: WEBrick seems to be more picky with URI formats than Thin. Here is a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748838/how-to-prevent-pipe-character-from-causing-a-bad-uri-error-in-rails-3-ruby-1-9-2/4741008#4741008

Answer (score 0):

We've had some issues where development and production environments that were seemingly identical behaved differently once deployed on heroku. A quick sanity check I like to do is to diff the local gemfile.lock to the one on heroku after the deploy process is complete. I know - we should lock our gem versions down more tightly and we will do, so don't consider this a best practice - but it unearthed some hard to track down issues, some of which were related to the fact that we have some devs on Windows and some on Mac and the gemfile.lock often had Windows specific gems which causes issues on heroku. Just something to consider.