# Can't override URL encoding for parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I've got a string that I want added to a URL variable, but I can't get Rails to *not* encode it.

Here's what I've got:

```
<%= link_to "Example", example_path(@resource, email: '*|EMAIL|*') %>
```

Output of that is:

```
http://example.com/example/123?email=%2A%7CEMAIL%7C%2A
```

But I want:

```
http://example.com/example/123?email=*|EMAIL|*
```

I've tried all of the following to get `*|EMAIL|*` to output correctly, but no go...

```
<%= link_to "Example", example_path(@resource, email: '*|EMAIL|*').html_safe %>
<%= raw link_to "Example", example_path(@resource, email: '*|EMAIL|*') %>
<%= link_to "Example", example_path(@resource, email: '*|EMAIL|*'.html_safe) %>
<%= link_to "Example", example_path(@resource, email: raw('*|EMAIL|*')) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like

`<%= link_to "Example", example_path(@resource) + "?email=*|EMAIL|*" %>`

which should also work like

`<%= link_to "Example", example_path(@resource) + "?email=*|#{@instance_var.upcase}|*" %>` if that's what you're looking to do.

Obviously it would be nice to use the rails path helper as intended, but as a last resort this should work.

You may also need to do something about the pipes, see:

[How to prevent pipe character from causing a Bad URI Error in Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748838/how-to-prevent-pipe-character-from-causing-a-bad-uri-error-in-rails-3-ruby-1-9-2)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the way `link_to` is implemented

```
def link_to(*args, &block)
  ...
    url = url_for(options)

    href = html_options['href']
    tag_options = tag_options(html_options)

    href_attr = "href=\"#{ERB::Util.html_escape(url)}\"" unless href
    "<a #{href_attr}#{tag_options}>#{ERB::Util.html_escape(name || url)}</a>".html_safe
  end
end
```

At the line `href_attr = "href=\"#{ERB::Util.html_escape(url)}\"" unless href`, the method
 `ERB::Util.html_escape` calls `to_s` on its argument before it does anything else, so whatever you use for `url` ends up getting escaped. Setting `href` in `html_options` looks like a way out, but `tag_options` also calls `ERB::Util.html_escape`.

You could just do

```
<a href="<%= example_path(@resource, email: '*|EMAIL|*'.html_safe) %>">Example</a>
```

I think.